# Remove property from all nodes in a Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've inherited a Neo4j database which is *massive* to say the least. I've been looking into it and noticed we store a large string in each node that is not used.

Let's say we have a few million nodes called `Post` and each `Post` has `Text`. I'd like to remove `Text` from each `Post` in the entire database. Can someone point me down the path of doing so via Cypher?

Also, how would you recommend safely doing this? Should I back up the entire instance incase something goes wrong? Or does Neo4j have a transactional history I can rely on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j does not allow NULL in the property so you can REMOVE Text from Post. Here is the syntax:

```
MATCH (p:Post) 
REMOVE p.text
```

However, you said you have a massive database so I would recommend to remove it by batch.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (p:Post) RETURN p",
  "REMOVE p.text",
  {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

It would create batches of 10k Post nodes then remove the property text then run it in parallel.

In any mass updates that you do, it is highly recommended to create a backup of the database.

Comment: Maybe show CALL {} IN TRANSACTIONS as well for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

This code should delete all of the `p.text` in the nodes that hold it:

```
  MATCH (p:Post)
  WHERE exists(p.text)
  REMOVE p.text
```